# Plot function of svm in R

Tags: r, svm

I have constructed a model of svm on a dataset of Fraud transactions , but when I am trying to plot the model it is neither showing any error nor showing any plot. My code is -

```
>library(e1071)  
>attach(FraudTransData)  
>model2<- svm(FraudTransData$Fraud_Ind~., data= FraudTransData)  
>plot(model2, FraudTransData)
```

I used the same plot function on another dataset **cats** and it showed a successful plot. I am unable to understand where have I gone wrong.

Comment: Please don't `attach` the data.  In your formula, you can use `svm(Fraud_Ind ~ ., data = FraudTransData)`

Comment: @akrun still not working

Comment: As far as the example is concerned, not reproducible

Answer (score -1):

How many inputs do you have?
The code you wrote does not work if you have more than two. You should add arguments `formula` and `slice` in the plot function.
Check the 'iris' example at `help(plot.svm)`

Comment: yeaa I have done even that, it is still not working